# SQL Server 2019 DATEADD no determinista

Tags: sql-server

Acabamos de actualizar el motor de SQL Server de 2008 a 2019 y queremos aumentar la compatibilidad con la base de datos, pero hay algunos campos calculados persistentes que dan error.

En 2008 la columna estaba creada así

```
[FechaHoraCita]  AS ([FechaCita]+CONVERT([time],[HoraCita],0)) PERSISTED
```

Ahora en 2019 dice que no es determinista.
También he intentado este cambio

```
alter table citas add FechaHoraCita as DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, FechaCita), HoraCita) PERSISTED
```

pero dice lo mismo.
Sin embargo según la documentación debería de funcionar https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-ver15

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar de la siguiente manera:

```
Create table miTabla (id int, FechaCita date, HoraCita time(0))
go
insert into miTabla (id, FechaCita, HoraCita)
values
(1,GETDATE(),'09:15');
go
```

Ahora el alter.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.miTabla
add FechaHoraCita as cast(FechaCita as datetime) 
+ cast(HoraCita as datetime) persisted;
go
```

[image: Resultado]

Answer (score 0):

Al final el problema venía no por el campo que estaba intentando crear sino por otro que ya existía y era tenía una fórmula no determinista en esta versión de SQL.
He eliminando el antiguo campo y ya me ha dejado hacer al alter table

Comment: Podrías indicar (a modo de ejemplo) qué fue lo que cambiaste? Le serviría mucho a otros con el mismo problema... edita tu respuesta

Comment: El tema es que también deberías modificar la pregunta, por que lo que entiendo, es que el problema estaba en otro lugar (no especificado en la pregunta)

Comment: Tenía 2 campos cada con fórmulas parecidas:
[FechaHoraCita]  AS ([FechaCita]+CONVERT([time],[HoraCita],0)) PERSISTED y 
[FechaHoraFinCita]  AS ([FechaCita]+CONVERT([time],[HoraCita],0)+CONVERT([time],[Duracion],0)) PERSISTED
Eliminé el primer campo e intenté recrearlo con una fórmula determinista compatible con SQL 2019 mediante:
alter table citas drop column FechaHoraCita
GO
alter table citas add FechaHoraCita as DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, FechaCita), HoraCita) PERSISTED
y me daba error. La solución fue hacer un ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN FechaHoraFinCita antes